# How to make a link to another page in python FPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, fpdf

In word processers like Microsoft Word, you can create hyperlinks that lead to another page of the same document you are reading. Using FPDF for Python, how would I create a link or hyperlink that leads to a page of itself?